# CheckBox (UserForm) is not checked when clicked by user

Tags: excel, vba, user-forums

I have two checkboxes in a UserForm (Excel) , with names e.g (`A_CB` , `B_CB`) .
The problem is when I click **A_CB** and afterwards I click **B_CB** , then B_CB is not checked automatically although the code under it is run correctly. 
I tried to delete `B_CB` and create again, but the same issue. 
**Strangely**, This problem is produced when I click `A_CB` then `B_CB` ,But If I clicked `B_CB` then `A_CB` then no problem.
I even set value for that checkbox = true ,but the same issue. 
In advance, grateful for all your help.

```
Dim ctrl As control
Dim control As control
 
Private Sub A_CB_Click()
 
  Set ctrl = Me.A_CB
 
    If ctrl = False Then
       ctrl.ForeColor = vbBlack
       ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData                'Clear All Filters
       ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False    'UnHide All Rows
       Exit Sub
    End If
 
    ctrl.ForeColor = vbBlue
 
    For Each control In Me.Controls
      If Not TypeOf control Is MSForms.Label Then
      If Not TypeOf control Is MSForms.Frame Then
          If control.name <> ctrl.name Then
             control.value = False
             control.ForeColor = vbBlack
          End If
      End If
      End If
    Next
 
End Sub
 
Private Sub B_CB_Click()
 
  Set ctrl = Me.B_CB
 
    If ctrl = False Then
       ctrl.ForeColor = vbBlack
       ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
       ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Exit Sub
    End If
 
    ctrl.ForeColor = vbBlue
 
    For Each control In Me.Controls
      If Not TypeOf control Is MSForms.Label Then
      If Not TypeOf control Is MSForms.Frame Then
          If control.name <> ctrl.name Then
             control.value = False
             control.ForeColor = vbBlack
          End If
      End If
      End If
    Next
 
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you place a break point on the click event.  You are probably executing it twice for each user click.  That would be caused by some other code not shown here.  Using this example code, it appeared to work just fine.

Comment: @igittr ,I revised my code and shortened it as possible (see above edited code), But the same issue.
Strangely, This problem is produced when I click `A_CB` then `B_CB` , If I clicked `B_CB` then `A_CB` then no problem.
The edited above code is the actual one I am using now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `b_CB` is clicked, you cycle through all controls and clear their values.  That change to `a_CB` is the same as a Click event, and the  code in `a_CB_Click` is executed.  That is updating the common variable called `ctrl`.  Then when the code continues within `b_CB_Click`, the name value of `ctrl` is no longer "b_CB" and there fore it gets cleared as well.